# Why Does Bash Report the Increment Error as an Error?

Tags: bash

This is super confusing to me, and couldn't find a man page to explain:

```
❯ export COUNTER=0
❯ ((COUNTER++))
❯ echo $?
1
❯ ((COUNTER++))
❯ echo $?
0
❯ echo $COUNTER
2
```

Why is the increment from 0 to 1 an error, but not 1 to 2?

Answer (score 0):

After some continued searching, this is the answer.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146773/why-bash-increment-n-0n-return-error

This is beyond confusing, I'm very surprised this makes sense.